# Jmeter response time for parallel execution

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, parallel-execution

I am using Jmeter 5.2, the application i am testing i have split them transaction modules. When i execute the test plan, the elapsed time, latency and connect time were added together for a module in the aggregate report. Since some of the requests runs parallel in a module, that report didn't produce expected results.

Later, i have moved the request to bzm-parallel controller modules. Where, some of the requests fails since some of the requests has to be executed after the previous request.

Is there any way to calculate the exact timetaken for the execution of 1 module in Jmeter considering the parallel execution of requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cumulative execution time of parallel requests equals to the execution time of the **longest** request so you need to take only that request which elapsed time exceeds its neighbors.

In order to filter out "not interesting" requests you can use one of below optoins:

1. Put parallel requests under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/)
2. If you're using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) for results analysis you can consider [`jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements)
3. You can remove the samplers you're not interested in via [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Simple controller inside your Parallel controller. This will help you execute the samples in parallel and in the correct sequence as arranged in the simple controller.

Sample:
Parallel Controller

- Simple Controller
  -- HTTP Sample 1
  -- HTTP Sample 2
  -- HTTP Sample 3

Output:
HTTP Sample 1
HTTP Sample 2
HTTP Sample 3